# Query not returning data on UI

Tags: permissions, relationships, fields

I have a lookup field on Contacts (say Customer__c). A REST API call is being used to display data on page (we are using angular for displaying UI and Salesforce is maintaining database). This API class has a query on Contacts which needs to display the data on UI. We are calling a field from Customer object (Customer__r.Patient__c). Patient__c is a text field.

The issue is the query is returning the appropriate data in Salesforce and Workbench but its only displaying the id of Customer__c in return on UI and not the required data i.e value of Patient__c.

I have checked the field level accessibility on the fields but that looks fine. Where else can I check the same?

```
SELECT Id, First_Name__c, name, Customer__r.Patient__c from Contact
```

Below is the response on UI:

```
Id:  "a2D5E00000009RcGRA"
First_Name__c: "John"
Name: "John Smith" 
Customer__c:"a0U5E000000JEuJGDE"
```

Comment: Have you try to use formula field for it. Check whether it is the same or not.

Comment: You mean to say add a formula field in query and check if its displaying the data on UI?

Comment: Yes i tried adding a formula field and it is displaying the correct data on UI.

Comment: Could you update your question with your code? I guess the error could be because of wrong JSON result sent from service method or unsuccessful parsing of result on client page.

Comment: @SaumyaRanjanSatapathy I have updated the question. Please suggest

Comment: Share code how you fire the REST request.